# footer at bottom width

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS for placing footer at the bottom

```
footer 
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

but then the footer is not in full width so I have to add `width: 100%;` to be

```
footer 
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Why do I have to add width, but when the footer is on normal position it has full width (when I do nothing with CSS)? Why browser is doing that?

EDIT: putting only `display: block;` doesn't fix, `<footer>` is by default block element.
Saying that's the default behavior of footer tag doesn't explain why it has full width when you do nothing with css.

Comment: This is standard element behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is doing that because that is the default behavior of the **footer** tag. That is why they declare the footer element as well as the new HTML5 elements to

```
display:block
```

see this normalize.css  https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css

You gotta declare the element to **display:block** so that you do not have to specify the width to it.

Check this.. http://dabblet.com/gist/4267350 . You may notice that the footer element is already stretching to the full width since it is already mentioned as **display:block** in their CSS.

Comment: what do you mean default? why does it have full width when I don put position: fixed; and bottom: 0;?

Comment: Well that made me test things and i too am now asking here and there why a block level element should resize itself after being declared position:fixed. Interesting. :) Upvoted your question.

Comment: tnx, and if u find an answer post it here cause i need to know :)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/#li-comment-232724 check this from chris coyier! **Just one of those weird things :p**

Comment: just one of those weird things... you can fix width by declaring body margin and padding 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because thats the default behaviour of the browser.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/